# What is the purpose of the html input tag value attribute?

Tags: html, input

I read about value attributes [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) here. It does not clearly mention why is it required for the input tag.
According to the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)
"value attribute specifies the value of an  element" what exactly does it mean by "value"?
Is it a just for humans to know what exactly a checkbox is for?
Or does the value has anything to do with the backend database?
Is the value attribute just for front end purpose only?

I know this question has been asked previously, but not all aspects of what a "value attribute" is were discussed. So I would like to raise the question again, and have another discussion about it.

Comment: Just to clear up potential confusion: w3schools is not "the" documentation. W3C has "the" documentation, w3schools has nothing to do with them.

Comment: VALUE attribute specifies the initial value for the text field. The VALUE attribute required for radio buttons and checkboxes, gives the value of the control when it is checked.

Comment: @Juhana Is there any official documentation on HTML5 or css3?

Comment: try this for HTML5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5

Comment: Thank you is there a similar documentation for CSS?

Comment: Yes, http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs. Official documentation is often called "specification" which helps with googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it a just for humans to know what exactly a checkbox is for?Does value attribute is just for frontend purpose only?**

The value property sets or returns the value of the value attribute of a checkbox/radiobutton.

> For checkboxes and radiobuttons, the contents of the value property do not appear in
>   the user interface. The value property only has meaning when
>   submitting a form. If a checkbox/radiobuttons is in checked state when the form is
>   submitted, the name of the checkbox/radiobuttons is sent with along with the value
>   of the value property (if the checkbox/radiobuttons is not checked, no information
>   is sent).

For example, when you are using `<input type="button" name="foo" value="Click"/>`, this will assign name 'Click' to your button. Same goes for text field: `<input name="subject" type="text" value="Default text" />` will show you a text field with 'Defaul text' in it.

Answer (score 1):

Value is where the actual value of the field is stored. Try changing it with jQuery or even with firebug and you will see that the submitted value will be changed!

Answer (score 0):

Given `<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar">` the submitted data for the checkbox will be `foo=bar` if the form it is inside is submitted and the checkbox is successful (the main additional criteria for which is that it is checked). The server side form handler can then use that information.

The value is not exposed to the user of the browser (unless they use a developer tool of some kind). That is the job of the `<label>` element.

Comment: For this case <input name="first_name" id="name" type="text"  placeholder="First Name" value="first_name"> what does value attribute specify?

Comment: The default value. i.e. it pre-populates the field with "first_name"

Comment: So it just pre-populates the form field value. In case user does not input anything and submits the form then would it be stored into the database?

Comment: It'll be submitted to the server. Beyond that, it depends on what the server is programmed to do with it.